# Is there a full text search engine for the works of J.R.R. Tolkien?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, j-r-r-tolkien, online-resources

When answering to another [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/169065/83101) on this site related to *A Song of Ice and Fire* by G.R.R. Martin, another user pointed out a site where it is possible to perform searches on the full texts of the published works by that author, namely [A Search of Ice and Fire](https://asearchoficeandfire.com/).

I was wondering if there is a similar tool for the works of J.R.R. Tolkien, where one can search his whole corpus of published works for a given term.

Comment: Personally, I'd suggest acquiring his works in epub format, loading them into [Calibre library manager](https://calibre-ebook.com/) and using the [Quality Check Plugin](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=125428) to search the entire library.

Comment: Seconded. That's how I do it. Simple and free. For statistics, there is http://lotrproject.com/statistics/books/

Comment: Thank you; the usefulness of an online search tool, anyway, is that one can look for references even on those books that he doesn't own.

Comment: To be crystalline clear: **I am not interested in illegal ways to acquire ebook versions of Tolkien texts!** I was only interested if there was a tool like the one available for ASOIAF also for Tolkien works, just for the purpose of a quick reference! I already own my copies of those books!

Comment: The [advanced google book search](https://books.google.com/advanced_book_search) is not that bad.  But I'm not certain it has all the features you require.

Comment: This might be better off asked on the [Literature Stack Exchange site](https://literature.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Jeff I fail to see why?

Comment: @Edlothiad - this isn't a question about the story, setting, characters, etc of LotR, but rather asking about the avaliability of resources for locating references within the text.  While there is obvious overlap, given that the stories are fantasy, this or more a question about the literary aspects (finding references, etc).

Comment: That's on-topic here [help/on-topic] background information or something is there. Edit: *Behind-the-scenes and fandom information* I'd call this "fandom information". Also are you certain it's on-topic there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The closest thing I can think of is The Tolkien Text Anthology.

It is an offline resource, but it has all of the works of J.R.R. Tolkien (including some of the rarer ones like *Vinyar Tengwar* and *Parma Eldalamberon*) in a single interface designed for searching.

[image: screenshot of the user interface of the Tolkien Text Anthology, labeled "TTA-Viewer"; the left side has has tree of work groupings, works and chapters, with "A. Middle-Earth Legendarium" -> "The Hobbit" -> "1. An Unexpected Party" expanded and highlighted. The right pant has page 22 of "The Hobbit" displayed and the word "Confusticate" highlighted in the text. Overlaid is a "Find" dialog running a search for "confusticate" and showing a list of all the matches with the first one (the aforementioned page of "The Hobbit" selected.]

<sub>I doubt it's any more legal than A Search of Ice and Fire though.</sub>

Comment: This does not seem to be available anywhere.

Comment: @Jonathon - It is an offline resource and very unofficial.

Answer (score 4):

### Not really

To the best of my knowledge, there is no search-engine like portal for Tolkien's published works. There have been many efforts to digitize some of the more popular ones (you can purchase e-books, of course, and the Internet Archive has a few in text-searchable form<sup>1</sup>), which would allow you to assemble one for yourself (Valorum's suggestion, in a comment on the question), but there are notable gaps in what's available.

The most notable are writings published in issues of [*Vinyar Tengwar*](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Vinyar_Tengwar) and [*Parma Eldalamberon*](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Parma_Eldalamberon), special interest newsletters published by the Elvish Linguistic Fellowship fan group. Both publications have received permission from Christopher Tolkien to publish essays (primarily language-related), but few exist in digitized form. It's this kind of limitation that dooms any attempt to create a "complete" Tolkien search engine: so many of his writings came into existence long before digitization was a thing, and weren't commercial enough to convert.

In theory there's nothing stopping someone from setting up an "incomplete" search engine (aside from the usual legal questions), just focused on the most "narrative" books, but to my knowledge nobody has done it; if they have, it certainly isn't prominent.

While not remotely what you're looking for, an interesting quasi-example is the [Eldamo lexicon](https://www.eldamo.org/), which is a reasonably-complete online dictionary of Tolkien's invented languages drawing from [most of](https://www.eldamo.org/content/references/index.html) Tolkien's published word-lists.

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm unclear on the legal implications of this, which is why I'm not posting links

Comment: And given the Tolkien Foundation's usual approach to the "the usual legal questions", there isn't going to be one.

Comment: So something like asearchoficeandfire.com would get shut down I guess?

Comment: @MattGutting I'm actually surprised the Game of Thrones one exists; I'd expect it to get sued into oblivion too, but apparently not

Comment: I'm sure there's something illegally (by most countries' takes) digitized somewhere.

Comment: If there are gaps in Tolkien's texts being illegally available online, I have yet to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Search engine, no... But there *is* a [concordance](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concordance), which is almost as good? But it might just be for ''The Hobbit''?

> an alphabetical index of the principal words in a book or the works of an author with their immediate contexts

https://wordsthatyouweresaying.blog/concordance/

Comment: This seems to be just *The Hobbit* though?

Comment: @ibid - Oh, I wasn't sure if it was covering just one book or not.